# Eclipse AWT, cannot debug

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, awt

I would like to be able to debug the following code in eclipse:

```
String local;   
try {
    local = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":" + port;
} catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
    local = "Network Error";
}
ip = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "IP: ", "Info", 
                             JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, null, local);
```

When I do: "run as > Java Application", everything works perfectly.
But when I try to debug (in eclipse Juno 32 or 64 bits), it never goes out of the line :

```
ip = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "IP: ", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, null, local);
```

**Additionnal Info:**

I am on Windows 7 64 bits. When I pause the code and look at the stack, it seems blocked at:

```
while (keepBlockingCT.get() &&
        ((extCondition != null) ? extCondition.evaluate() : true)) {
    getTreeLock().wait();
}
```

it is in the file/Class WaitDispatchSupport in the package java.awt;

I use the JDK 1.7(up to date JDK)

**Edit:**
Also, the dialog never shows up

Comment: Maybe it's related. http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6178755

Comment: So, it sounds like you're calling AWT/Swing methods outside the AWT Event Dispatch thread. Put the JOptionPane.showXYZ() call into this: `javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {public void run() { JOptionPane.showXYZ(); }})` More information: [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Comment: I meant: /in your program/, put the JOptionPane call into (...). The page states that 1.5.0 and 1.6.0 are affected versions.

Comment: I did:
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {public void run() { 
    ip=(String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "IP: ", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, null, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":" + port);
}

And it didn't worked...I think it is what ou wanted me to do?

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry, then I don't know how to help you.

Comment: I think it may be a configuration problem....the program works perfectly each time I run it outside the debugger